# overflow:hidden won't help to prevent horizontal scrolling

Tags: responsive-design, horizontal-scrolling

Generally, `overflow:hidden` solves all my horizontal scrolling problems, but in the following case it doesn't and it also disables the vertical scrolling.

If you'll mark a text and drag left the screen view (while responsive), you would be able to see the horizontal scrolling problem. here is a link:

http://nexus.techsaran.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have an adsense block which has a hardcoded width of 728px.

So whenever the viewport is < 728 px, this div will extend beyond the right hand edge of the page, hence the horizontal scroll bar.

**Edit**

> Can you please tell me where you've found it

It's in this block of code here

```
<div style='text-align:center'><div class='adsense' style='display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px;'>
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- 728x90 -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-5337874066772271"
     data-ad-slot="6784283332"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
</div>
```

Whenever you have horizontal scrolling like you described, it's generally an indication that there's an element which is too wide, so that's what I was looking for. In this case you can actually see that the ad is too wide if you narrow your window. I used web inspector (similar to firebug) to confirm.

Sometimes you can't actually see the element which is causing the problem. In web inspector, if you hover over an element in the code view, it will be highlighted in the page view, so this helps.

FYI, there are ways to work with Adsense on responsive sites. [Checkout this link](http://www.labnol.org/internet/google-adsense-responsive-design/25252/) to get you started

Good luck!

Comment: Oh thank you David! I can't manage to find this block with firebug.

Can you please tell me where you've found it\how you have tracked it down?

Comment: David, I swear, I searched all the files (PHP, Jquery, CSS), and also after the wide adsense ad at the bootom of the site, and just couldn't find any input of "728px"... So, not only I haven't manage to track it down with firebug, I have no idea where to even start to make it "Display:none".

Comment: @ben It looks to me as if this is a Drupal site. You could check if this adsense block is being added by your theme or a Drupal extension

Comment: @ben to clarify, I'm using web inspector to examine the DOM (as opposed to the HTML). Examining the DOM lets you find and examine elements which have been added to the page your CMS and JS

Comment: @ben, maybe you could check with the theme developers?

Comment: David, I've re installed the theme and flipped it's style css (from LTR to RTL) all over again, and suddenly the problem was solved:

I think I might confused 2 different Horizontal scrolling problems - 1 at the live demo at the theme caused by the hardcoded adsense (The theme developers gave me short answers that led me to believe I also have them hard coded in my site).

The second was a Webform sideform that had wide input fields that caused the problem at my end... It's wired because only after some changes they seem wide to me, but for now I took care of their CSS. :|